# Error on adding macro for response helper chained with json method in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-response

I'm working on a Laravel 5 Application that only uses API routes. I created a macro to extend the add cookie method of the response helper. But I encountered an error that my macro doesn't exist.

We are using this for returning response:

```php
return response()->json($data, $status)
  ->cookie(
     'COOKIE_NAME',
     $value,
     $expiration,
     '/',
     app()->environment('production') ? config('app.domain') : null,
     app()->environment('production'),
     true
  );
```

as the data beyond the expiration is always the same for all endpoint with cookie, I want to create a macro that will automatically adds that data to the cookie and reduce the code to this:

```php
return response()->json($data, $status)
  ->httpCookie('COOKIE_NAME, $value, $expiration);
```

I have created a `ResponseServiceProvider` and add the macro using `Response::macro` method.

Here is my macro code:

```php
public function boot()
{
  Response::macro('httpCookie', function ($name, $value, $expiration) {
    $isProd = app()->environment('production');
    return response()->cookie(
      $name, 
      $value,
      $expiration,
      '/',
      $isProd ? config('app.domain') : null,
      $isProd,
      true
    );
  });
}
```

Then trying to test the endpoint, I ran to an error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::httpCookie does not exist.
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What is the full namespace of your `Response` class from service provider? (It could be `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response` or `Illuminate\Http\Response`)

Comment: @Shizzen83 i'm using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at the [Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php) class, the Response Facade proxies the [Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php) class. Though the ResponseFactory is also macroable, it is used for a different purpose.

So please add a macro to the correct class, in this case I think [Illuminate\Http\Response](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

public function boot()
{
  Response::macro('httpCookie', function ($name, $value, $expiration) {
    $isProd = app()->environment('production');
    return $this->cookie(
      $name, 
      $value,
      $expiration,
      '/',
      $isProd ? config('app.domain') : null,
      $isProd,
      true
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: You should explain why it works on the underlying class and not on the facade itself.

Comment: This works for me.
But can you explain why this works on `Illuminate\Http\Response` not `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response` as what Shizzen83 said?

Comment: I have added further explanation.